# handling special characters in fetch xml

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I need to Manage the 'AccountText' variable, so if I'am passing a value with special characters for exemple "MC&CO", I should not get an error.

```
var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>" + 
                "<entity name='contact'>" + 
                "<attribute name='contactid' />" + 
                "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='parentcustomerid' operator='eq' name='" + AccountText + "' value='" + AccountID + "' /></filter>" +
                "</entity>" + 
                "</fetch>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You could encode the `AccountText` before including it in the query:

```
AccountText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(AccountText);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know FetchXML uses XML's native special character handling so you can escape the ampersand as `&amp;`

For example:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
    <entity name="account" >
        <attribute name="accountid" />
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="MC&amp;Co" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

To do it for all special characters, there are several ways to escape a string for XML. The quickest may be to use the System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape() method in the `System.Web` library:

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
string encodedXml = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xml);
```

which outputs:
`&lt;node&gt;it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;`

There are more examples [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Aron , but i want something more generic,to can handle all expetions.

Comment: I'am not using .net/c#.

Comment: You might want to tag the language you're using as well.

Comment: ah ..sorry .I'am using JS